# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. Error while sending outlook mail using c# webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-webapi, smtpclient

I'm not sure about which `mailServer` should be using for microsoft.com mail.
This is my code:

```
string toemail = "v-***@microsoft.com";
string subject =  "Testing Mail";
string mailBody = "<p>Hi..<br />This is testing email<br />Regards,<br />Nikita</p>";
// string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString(); 
string senderEmail = "v-****@microsoft.com";
string sendPwd = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPwd"].ToString();
SmtpClient smtpCl = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 25);
                smtpCl.EnableSsl = true;
smtpCl.Timeout = 1000000;
smtpCl.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpCl.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpCl.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, sendPwd);

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toemail, subject, mailBody);

mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
smtpCl.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: port 465 for ssl/tls

Comment: @Charlieface SmtpClient only supports STARTTLS, not SMTP over an SSL-only port. So I think a non-SSL port is correct.

Comment: StartTLS port 587

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use port 587, see [POP and IMAP email settings for Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-and-imap-email-settings-for-outlook-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353).

```
SmtpClient smtpCl = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587);
```

Comment: thank you @iamdlm, its working . I have change this to smtpClient smtpCl = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587); But my sender mail server is :- microsoft.com , and I am not able to check POP and smtp setting . May i know , smtp server value for v-***@microsoft.com

Comment: Also in sender mail , two factor authentication is on.